# SSRS 2012. Count value and then group on that count

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Still a newbie, still struggling.

Using SSRS 2012.  We report using cubes, so I cannot change the MDX.

My query returns a varying number of clients with orders. I need to count the number of client orders, group by that count and then give a distinct count of clients in that order group, eg

```
client  orders
2         1
5         1
5         1
12        1
12        1
123       1
123       1
123       1
123       1
```

What I need is:

```
 no. of orders      unique count of clients
 1 order                   1
 2 orders                  2
 3 orders                  0
 4 orders                  1
 total clients             4
```

I've tried to create expressions or calculated fields, but falling short in either the layout or the inability to use aggregates in the grouping/calculated fields.

I believe creating a calculated member (count of orders by client) in the Query Designer screen would solve my issues, but I don't know how to achieve this.  (I could be totally wrong in this).

Any help much appreciated, as I now cannot think straight.

EDIT - following is de-identified MDX query (It's a very simple query.)  Please forgive poor formatting.

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[Order Count] } ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY { ([Client].[D_ID].[D_ID].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Order].[ReN].[ReN].ALLMEMBERS * [Order].[Order Group].[Order Group].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Order].[Order Type].[Order Type].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Order].[Expiry Date].[Expiry Date].ALLMEMBERS 
* [Order].[Revoked Date].[Revoked Date].ALLMEMBERS ) }
DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, 
MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Order].[Revoked Date].&[1899-12-30T00:00:00] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [Client].[Ind].&[1], [Client].[Ind].&[2], [Client].[Ind].&[3] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [N].[RO].&[A] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [N].[R].&[CN] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM ( SELECT ( { [CS].[Status].&[Active] } ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [Order]))))) 
WHERE ( [CS].[Status].&[Active], 
[N].[R].&[CN], 
[N].[RO].&[A], 
[Client].[Ind].CurrentMember ) 
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, BACK_COLOR, FORE_COLOR, FORMATTED_VALUE, FORMAT_STRING, FONT_NAME, FONT_SIZE, FONT_FLAGS
```

Comment: If you are using query editor it generates a MDX script that fetches the data you specify in the query editor. Share that script with us in order to help you.

Comment: Added MDX query as requested

Comment: Still looking for an answer to this - it's the last thing I need to fix for a giant report.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how is the setup of your Dataset but if you can write a SQL Query on it, you can try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(ORDERS,' ','order(s)') as [No. of Orders]
    ,COUNT(CLIENTS) as [Unique Count of Clients]
FROM
   (SELECT CLIENTS,COUNT(ORDERS) AS ORDERS FROM TABLENAME GROUP BY CLIENTS) Alias
GROUP BY ORDERS
```

Then you can just put it on a simple Table.

Comment: Note the OP states the report datasource is an OLAP cube, which cannot be queried using SQL.

Comment: Thanks Aldrin, but I cannot use this.